# Restructure a json in scala play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The following code gets the request body and validates and creates a json:
        object ValidateDBConfigJson {

```
implicit val reads: Reads[ValidateDetails] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String].filter(JsonValidationError("Invalid name"))(_.length > 0) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read[String].filter(JsonValidationError("Invalid email"))(_.length > 0) and
)(ValidateDetails.apply _)
```

}

```
def index() = Action { implicit request =>
val bodyAsJson = request.body.asJson.get
bodyAsJson.validate[ValidateDetails] match {
  case success: JsSuccess[ValidateDetails] => {
    Ok(Json.parse("succeeded!"))
  }
  case JsError(error) =>
    BadRequest(JsError.toJson(error))
}
```

}

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "obj.name": [
        {
          "msg": [
          "error.expected.jsstring"
          ],
          "args": []
        }
    ],
    "obj.email": [
         {
            "msg": [
            "Invalid email"
            ],
            "args": []
         }
    ]
}
```

I want structured in  the  following  format:

```
{
 "ErrorMessages" : 
    [
    "error.expected.jsstring", 
    "Invalid email"
    ]
 }
```

Comment: What code exactly gives the `BadRequest(JsError.toJson(error))` exception? You have only posted JSON; please include your code so we can help you debug it :-)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preamble: when I am parsing JSON using Play I prefer to use case class/objects rather than implicit reads, so this answer will cover that method of doing this. There may be a simpler method of doing this with implicit reads but I am not as familiar with implicit reads.

Firstly, define a `case class` for everything you will be taking from JSON:

```
object Input {
  case class Err(msg: Seq[String], args: Seq[String])

  object Err {
    implicit val format: OFormat[Err] = Json.format[Err]
  }

  case class ValidateDetails(`obj.name`: Seq[Err], `obj.email`: Seq[Err])

  object ValidateDetails {
    implicit val format: OFormat[ValidateDetails] = Json.format[ValidateDetails]
  }
}
```

Note: Play won't know how to handle user-defined case classes so I've made one for `Err` as well. The `implicit val format: OFormat[ValidateDetails] = Json.format[ValidateDetails]` and `implicit val format: OFormat[Err] = Json.format[Err]` lines are magic and do all of the reads/writes for you.

Next, define a case class for your output JSON and define a function which will turn your input case class into your output one:

```
object Output {
  case class OutputJson(`ErrorMessages`: Seq[String])

  object OutputJson {
    implicit val format: OFormat[OutputJson] = Json.format[OutputJson]
  }

  // take msg Seq from name & email and add together into single Seq
  def inputToOutput(input: Input.ValidateDetails): OutputJson = {
    OutputJson(input.`obj.name`.flatMap(_.msg) ++ input.`obj.email`.flatMap(_.msg))
  }
}
```

Finally, put this into a method which maps to a POST route in your `routes` file:

```
def index() = Action { implicit request =>
  val bodyAsJson = request.body.asJson.get
  bodyAsJson.validate[Input.ValidateDetails] match {
    case success: JsSuccess[Input.ValidateDetails] =>
      // turn the JSON into the Output case class and parse that as JSON
      val output: JsValue = Json.toJson(Output.inputToOutput(success.value))
      Ok(output)
    case JsError(error) =>
      BadRequest(JsError.toJson(error))
  }
}
```

Now, if you run the Play app on port 9000 and POST to http://localhost:9000/ with the below JSON body...

```
{
    "obj.name": [
        {
          "msg": [
          "error.expected.jsstring"
          ],
          "args": []
        }
    ],
    "obj.email": [
         {
            "msg": [
            "Invalid email"
            ],
            "args": []
         }
    ]
}
```

...the output will be:

```
{
    "ErrorMessages": [
        "error.expected.jsstring",
        "Invalid email"
    ]
}
```

I hope this answers your question.